# Ionic 2 push notification not triggered in android app

Tags: ionic2

Ionic 2 push notification `pushObject.on('notification')` not triggered in android app(No push notifications received) but `pushObject.on('registration')` and `pushObject.on('error')` are triggered. Can anyone help me?

Comment: how are you testing this ?: emulator or device and whats the device ?

Comment: I test it using android device

Comment: may i know the model of the device ?

Comment: HUAWEI GR3 2017

Comment: and I send notification using firebase

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my xiaomi phone, They have an annoying batter manager. try the following and see.

Step 1: Go to settings --> advanced settings --> battery manager --> protected apps, then find the app you want to see notifications from, and protect it. This is "whitelisting" the app so Huawei's overeager software doesn't shut it down for no reason.

Step 2: Go to settings --> apps --> advanced --> ignore battery optimizations, then find the app and ignore it. Don't be tricked by the misleading wording, "ignoring" the app actually means to let it run, because you're telling the battery optimization function, aka Doze, to "ignore" that app.

Step 3: Go to settings --> notification panel & status bar --> notification center, then find the app, then activate "allow notifications" and also "priority display". You have to activate the priority part too to make sure you get notifications. I've tried just activating allow notifications but not priority and I still didn't get notifications from that app.

[Original Source](https://www.forbes.com/sites/bensin/2016/07/04/push-notifications-not-coming-through-to-your-huawei-phone-heres-how-to-fix-it/#6b70da721ccc)